# border radius rounded corners into parent and child <div>

Tags: html, css

I have some problem with hover on div, which has border-radius.

When i hover the div there is small line with color that not similar with hover color.

html code:

```
<div class="grid_veiw_case_active">
    <div> some text</div>

    <div class="delete_div">
        <div class="delete"><p class="button_text"></p></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

css(part) code:

```
.grid_veiw_case_active {
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-color: #404040;
   border-radius: 5px;
   background: #7d7d7d;  
   width: 254px;
}
.grid_veiw_case_active .delete {
   border-top: 1px solid #969696;
   width: 100%;
   height: 38px;
   -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
   -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
   -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
   -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
   background: #c1c0c0;

}

.grid_veiw_case_active .delete:hover {
   background: #d06d70;

}
```

code link http://jsfiddle.net/Xbj3b/.
image that illustrats problem
 [image]

Comment: What's your browser and OS?

Comment: it looks great to me, in chrome, so perhaps it is a different browser's issue? I would check to see which browsers support rounded borders and go from there.

Comment: IMO you are worried about 1 pixel. If this isn't a design-based site, and your users see a 1px gap, i would worry more about the fact your is content lacking versus a 1px gap

Comment: I would take (if possible) a different `border-color` (example #ddd) and test it out in different browser...

Comment: huge wall of css, to make such simple thing.

Comment: 2008 windows(server), chrome. And it is design-based site, so that why i am worried about 1 pixel

Answer (score 0):

Add  `border-radius: 0px;` to your hover state.

Comment: that results in the inner div being not round at all and the sharp edge of it overlaps the round edge of the other one then or did you mean something different http://jsfiddle.net/Xbj3b/8/

Comment: You may need to tweak the value to get exactly what you want. The anti-aliasing on layered rounded corners that the browsers use is kind of crappy.

Comment: there is way to set border-radius 3.3px, and if i don't find better solve, i will use such kind solve